# insert form input value in database in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one form input like

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="SITE_URL" id="SITE_URL" required>
```

So what I want is to add name's value `SITE_URL` in one database column and the value I insert in other column like

```
v_name      l_value
---------- ----------
SITE_URL  "Inserted value "
```

`l_value` is inserted completely but `v_name` is not inserted
my `$_post` array is like:

```
Array
(
    [SITE_URL] => value that i inserted
)
```

My code is:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $post["l_value"] = $this->input->post('SITE_URL');
        $post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');
        $addPage = $this->admin_model->addSiteSetting($post);
        exit;
```

}

And `addSiteSetting` function is:

```
 public function addSiteSetting($ins){

    $this->db->insert('tbl_setting', $ins);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `$this->input->post('');` why you set blank ??

Comment: i  don't know what i have to set there. that's what i want.

Comment: what you want to store in `$post["v_name"]` Or in DB table ?

Comment: just remove `$post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');`

Comment: i want to store SITE_URL in  table column v_name

Comment: if your name[SITE_URL] is static then why don't you save it directly

Comment: $post["v_name"] = 'SITE_URL';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process `$_POST` in `foreach` loop to get both names and their values, like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
      $post = array();
      foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
      $post["l_value"] = $value;
      $post["v_name"] = $name;
      }

        $addPage = $this->admin_model->addSiteSetting($post);
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass`SITE_URL` as static name for `$post["v_name"]`

you need to change just one line `$post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');` To `$post["v_name"] = 'SITE_URL';`

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $post["l_value"] = $this->input->post('SITE_URL');
        $post["v_name"] = 'SITE_URL';
        $addPage = $this->admin_model->addSiteSetting($post);
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the following line. Because here you store the blank value into the v_name. That's why v_name doesn't get any value and keep it empty.

```
$post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');
```

And Instead of the above line you need to add this line:

```
$post["v_name"] = 'SITE_URL';
```

Answer (score -1):

You have

```
$post["l_value"] = $this->input->post('SITE_URL');
    $post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');
```

remove

```
$post["v_name"] = $this->input->post('');
```

Comment: then the v_name field remains blank